# sm.density.compare(): displaying multiple density estimations in a single plot

Tags: r, density-plot

I am trying to overlay three different density plots in R to create one plot displaying all three lines (superimpose). I have the `sm` package installed/loaded but I have tried using it with my data to no avail. 
I created three individual data plots simply using `density()` and plotting the values. My code looks like this:

```
library(sm)

set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(126, 0.3, 1.2)
z <- rnorm(93, -0.5, 0.7)
dx <- density(x)
dy <- density(y)
dz <- density(z)

plot(dx)
plot(dy)
plot(dz)
```

But when I try using the `sm.density.compare()` to overlay the graphs:

```
sm.density.compare(dx,dy,model="equal")
```

I get an error that says:

> Error in sm.density.compare(dx, dy, model = "equal") :
>   sm.density.compare can handle only 1-d data trace:

Anyone know how I can fix this? I've researched quite a lot but with no success. I am fairly new to R and could really use the help.

Comment: Nope! Its perfect, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you want to use `sm.density.compare()`, then do not use `density()`.**

`sm.density.compare()` itself is doing density estimation. Specifically, it is doing density estimation on grouped data, so that you can plot density of different groups on the same graph.

Here is what you really need to do:

```
## three groups, each of length: length(x), length(y), length(z)
group.index <- rep(1:3, c(length(x), length(y), length(z)))
## collect data together and use sm.density.compare()
den <- sm.density.compare(c(x,y,z), group = group.index, model = "equal")
## plot will be generated automatically
```

[image: den3]

When using `model = "equal"`, `sm.density.compare()` has returned values. Have a look at `str(den)`:

```
List of 4
 $ p          : num 0
 $ estimaate  : num [1:3, 1:50] 2.37e-07 3.81e-06 6.06e-10 2.17e-06 2.26e-05 ...
 $ eval.points: num [1:50] -4.12 -3.94 -3.76 -3.58 -3.4 ...
 $ h          : num 0.376
```

`h` contains bandwidth used for all density estimation, `eval.points` contains estimation points, while `estimaate` is a matrix, of density estimation values. (*Adrian has a typo here, it should be "estimate", not "estimaate", LOL*).

All functions from `sm` package, starting with prefix `sm.` accept optional arguments `...`, passed to `sm.options`. Have a read on `?sm.options`, and you will find you have full control on the colour display, line type and line width, bandwidth selection method, etc.

Reference band will only be added to data of two groups. I.e., for pairwise comparison, `sm.density.compare()` can do more. For example:

```
den2 <- sm.density.compare(c(x,y), group = rep(1:2, c(length(x), length(y))),
                           model = "equal")
```

[image: den2]

```
> str(den2)
List of 6
 $ p          : num 0.22
 $ estimate   : num [1:2, 1:50] 4.92e-06 2.70e-05 2.51e-05 1.00e-04 1.09e-04 ...
 $ eval.points: num [1:50] -4.12 -3.94 -3.76 -3.58 -3.4 ...
 $ upper      : num [1:50] 0.00328 0.00373 0.00459 0.00614 0.00886 ...
 $ lower      : num [1:50] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ h          : num 0.44
```

where `lower` and `upper` gives the bound of reference band / confidence region.

---

**If you use `density()`, then do not use `sm.density.compare()`**

```
## set universal estimation range
xlim <- range(x, y, z)
dx <- density(x, from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2], n = 200)
dy <- density(y, from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2], n = 200)
dz <- density(z, from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2], n = 200)
```

In this situation, density estimation for each group is done independently. Each "density" object is a list, for example:

```
> str(dx)
List of 7
 $ x        : num [1:200] -2.64 -2.61 -2.58 -2.55 -2.52 ...
 $ y        : num [1:200] 0.023 0.026 0.0291 0.0323 0.0356 ...
 $ bw       : num 0.31
 $ n        : int 100
 $ call     : language density.default(x = x, n = 200, from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2])
 $ data.name: chr "x"
 $ has.na   : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "density"
```

`x` is evaluation points, `y` is estimated density, `bw` is bandwidth used. You will see, that `dx$bw`, `dy$bw` and `dz$bw` are different, due to independent estimation. However, you can manually specify a universal `bw` when calling `density()`, by using argument `bw`. See `?density`, and I will give no example here.

Now, to overlay those density plot, you need to do yourself.

```
## set global plotting range
ylim <- range(dx$y, dy$y, dz$y)
## make plot
plot(dx$x, dx$y, col = 1, lwd = 2, type = "l", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
lines(dy$x, dy$y, col = 2, lwd = 2)
lines(dz$x, dz$y, col = 3, lwd = 2)
```

[image: do it yourself]